# JPA mapping on non-primary columns uni-directional

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 tables Customer and CustomerAgreement.

Structure of Customer :

```
primary key : id, validFrom

|----------------------------------|
|id | validFrom | custName | region|
|---|-----------|----------|-------|
| 1 | 54353     | Volvo    | APAC  |
| 1 | 54453     | Merc     | APAC  |
|----------------------------------|
```

Structure of CustomerAgreement

```
 primary key : id, validFrom

|-----------------------------------------|
|id | validFrom | custId | name           |
|---|-----------|--------|--------------  |
|20 | 1867      |   2    | Merc_EOD_AGR   |
|21 | 8535      |   2    | Merc_SOD_AGR   |
|25 | 8335      |   1    | Volvo_SOD_AGR  |
|26 | 8635      |   1    | Volvo_SOD_AGR  |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

Relationship between Customer and CustomerAgreement is 1-N.
Customer has to be the owning side, i.e. if i fetch customer i should be able to get all the customeragreements.

Below is the JPA class implementation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer"
        , schema = "dbo"
)
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {


    private CustomerId id;
    private String custName;
    private Set<CustomerAgreement> customerAgreement;

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "validFrom", column = @Column(name = "validFrom", nullable = false))})
    public CustomerId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(CustomerId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "custName", nullable = false, length = 64)
    public String getCustName() {
        return this.custName;
    }

    public void setCustName(String custName) {
        this.custName = custName;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity = CustomerAgreement.class, mappedBy = "customerId")
    public Set<CustomerAgreement> getCustomerAgreement() {
        return customerAgreement;
    }

    public void setCustomerAgreement(Set<CustomerAgreement> customerAgreement) {
        this.customerAgreement = customerAgreement;
    }

}

@Embeddable
public class CustomerId implements java.io.Serializable {


    private int id;
    private int validFrom;

    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name = "validFrom", nullable = false)
    public int getValidFrom() {
        return this.validFrom;
    }

    public void setValidFrom(int validFrom) {
        this.validFrom = validFrom;
    }


    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((this == other)) return true;
        if ((other == null)) return false;
        if (!(other instanceof CustomerId)) return false;
        CustomerId castOther = (CustomerId) other;

        return (this.getId() == castOther.getId())
                && (this.getValidFrom() == castOther.getValidFrom());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;

        result = 37 * result + this.getId();
        result = 37 * result + this.getValidFrom();
        return result;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CustomerAgreement"
        , schema = "dbo"
)
public class CustomerAgreement implements java.io.Serializable {

    private CustomerAgreementId customerAgreementId;
    private String name;
    private int customerId;

    @EmbeddedId
    public CustomerAgreementId getCustomerAgreementId() {
        return this.customerAgreementId;
    }

    public void setCustomerAgreementId(CustomerAgreementId customerAgreementId) {
        this.customerAgreementId = customerAgreementId;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "customerId", nullable = false)
    public int getCustomerId() {
        return this.customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
}


@Embeddable
public class CustomerAgreementId  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int id;
     private int validFrom;


    @Column(name="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name="validFrom", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public int getValidFrom() {
        return this.validFrom;
    }

    public void setValidFrom(int validFrom) {
        this.validFrom = validFrom;
    }


   public boolean equals(Object other) {
         if ( (this == other ) ) return true;
         if ( (other == null ) ) return false;
         if ( !(other instanceof CustomerAgreementId) ) return false;
         CustomerAgreementId castOther = ( CustomerAgreementId ) other; 

         return (this.getId()==castOther.getId())
 && (this.getValidFrom()==castOther.getValidFrom());
   }

   public int hashCode() {
         int result = 17;

         result = 37 * result + this.getId();
         result = 37 * result + this.getValidFrom();
         return result;
   }   


}
```

I want to fetch Customer and CustomerAgreements based on customerId. The mapping between Customer and CustomerAgreement is on id column in Customer table and customerId in CustomerAgreement table.

When i try to fetch i get the error

```
Foreign key (FKfclni2iqr01tuwaclmd7mtbpv:CustomerAgreement [customerId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (Customer [id,validFrom])
```

I tried to replace int data type for customerId in CustomerAgreement class to Customer as below

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Customer getCustomerId() {
        return this.customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Customer customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
```

still not working getting the same error

Comment: the error is quite explicit : your foreign key should have the same number of columns as the referenced primary key, so you can't just have a foreign key with a single column `customerId` because the table customer have a primary key with two columns, you should have a foreign key with two columns `customerId` and `customerValidFrom`. The mapping should be like this : `@JoinColumns(@JoinColumn(name="customerId", referencedColumnName="id"),@JoinColumn(name="customerValidFrom", referencedColumnName="validFrom"))`

Comment: yeah that should be the ideal mapping, but customer agreements can be edited independently of customer, which essentially means is that customer ValidFrom and customerAgreement validFrom may not match. but still i need to fetch all customerAgreements for a customer irrespective of validFrom

Comment: ok I think your mapping should be ok with `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="custId", referencedColumnName = "id")`

Comment: still getting the same error :(

Comment: hum I don't think it's possible because the referencedColumnName should always be unique, one possible solution is to use a dao method to retrieve the customers with `id` = `customerId`

Comment: or you can add an extra **unique** column in the table `customer` -> `custId`, then the mapping `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="custId", referencedColumnName = "custId")` in `CustomerAgreement` will work

Comment: :( unfortunately its legacy database, we wont be allowed to have a new column

Comment: so you should go with a `dao`

Comment: Hibernate's `@JoinFormula` could possibly be of assistance in definining a less restrictive join(https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/12/06/how-to-customize-an-entity-association-join-on-clause-with-hibernate-joinformula/). JPA compliant alternatives would be to use an intermediate join entity based on a database view.

Comment: @AlanHay i tried something like this with JoinFormula, but does not works it expects composite id

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinFormula("(SELECT customerId FROM CustomerAgreement CA WHERE CA.custId = id)")
    public Set<CustomerAgreement> getCustomerAgreement() {
        return customerAgreement;
    }

Comment: A Foreign key refering com.ambuj.schema.Customer from com.ambuj.schema.CustomerAgreement has the wrong number of column. should be 2